# MSE dont play video if mimetype have audio codecs in chrome

Tags: javascript, mp4, live-streaming, fmp4

I have an fmp4(h264/aac) stream from the server, and a Wsplayer player, if the stream without sound the video plays in firefox and chrome browsers, but if the stream with sound in chrome the video does not play

I establish a connection via websocket

if mediasource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D4028"'); to work
and if mediasource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4D4028, mp4a.40.2"'); dont work

Comment: Why not just use HTTP and skip MediaSource entirely?

Comment: Alas. But there are two points:
1) HTTP accumulates the buffer and does not clear it, as a result, sooner or later the client will run out of RAM
2) According to the conditions, you must use a websocket connection

Comment: Chromium, at least, is pretty good about *not* keeping old buffered data when streaming live.  You can stream indefinitely via HTTP this way.

Comment: According to the conditions, a websocket connection is required, since in the future it is expected to set up communication through messages with the server within the framework of this connection, and you still need to figure out why this will happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I managed to solve the problem:

1. This is a division within one MediaSource of two sourceBuffers separately for video and audio on the client
2. On the server side, create two init fragments for video and audio

Comment: Yes. Basically you need to do two separate `.addSourceBuffer` (one for video codec, and another for audio codec).